# Ways to prevent "npm run build" everytime I make FE changes while serving FE(react) and BE(node) on same server endpoint

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am stuck on a project that uses same server (8080) to server FE(react) as well as BE (node).

The implementation of the project is similar to [Click here](https://medium.com/@svsh227/serve-the-react-application-by-node-server-add-node-server-in-react-app-c71e5fb0a895#:%7E:text=The%20URL%20%E2%80%9Clocalhost%3A3000%E2%80%9D%20is%20calling%20an%20API%20(default%20%E2%80%9C/%E2%80%9D%20API%20)%20of%20node%20server%2C%20and%20according%20to%20the%20code%20of%20server%2C%20it%20is%20serving%20the%20react%20app%20using%20react%20build.%0AWhen%20you%20do%20any%20change%20in%20your%20react%20app%2C%20you%20need%20to%20create%20your%20updated%20build%20using%20the%20command%20%E2%80%9Cnpm%20run%20build%E2%80%9D:%7E:text=The%20URL%20%E2%80%9Clocalhost%3A3000%E2%80%9D%20is%20calling%20an%20API%20(default%20%E2%80%9C/%E2%80%9D%20API%20)%20of%20node%20server%2C%20and%20according%20to%20the%20code%20of%20server%2C%20it%20is%20serving%20the%20react%20app%20using%20react%20build.%0AWhen%20you%20do%20any%20change%20in%20your%20react%20app%2C%20you%20need%20to%20create%20your%20updated%20build%20using%20the%20command%20%E2%80%9Cnpm%20run%20build%E2%80%9D.)

The problem I am facing is that I have rerun "npm run build" every time I make any changes on FE side.

Please someone help me with a solution, so that I don't have to run build every time while also serving FE and BE on same server ?

Comment: Depends on what sort of changes you're making, can you elaborate?

Comment: Everything, suppose a log, or a div. Everything. Problem is that the node server is serving the build folder, due to which I have to run "npm run build" everytime for my changes to updated in build folder